# ROS kinect distance information

Tags: ros, kinect, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want distance information from kinect.

1,
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

2,
rostopic echo camera/depth/image

The value are 0,0,0,0,127,255,2,5,0,0.....

what is this value?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67882/ros-kinect-distance-information/) by [Ichiro suzuki](https://answers.ros.org/users/5224/ichiro-suzuki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is your image as mentioned in the topic title. Please read the  [documentation of openni_launch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch) where the topic depth/image is explained. This is a message as sensor_msgs/Image. Look [this page](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) to know how read it.

However if you want to read the distance (depth) I advise you to use camera/depth/points inside a node as PointCloud2 or XYZ point cloud using PCL.

---

Originally posted by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) with karma: 411 on 2013-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4